# What is the proper way to fetch data from server with ReactJS and Flux architecture where no Store presented?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have a front-end application written in js with ReactJS library. I do use Flux architecture to support my data flow. At the beginning, when front-end initializes, it retrieves data from server (like initial appstate) - different entities, saves them to appropriate stores. These stores trigger 'change' event, and all  components render with data from store. Later, front-end works taking if necessary data from these stores.

Now I need to build a kind of report and building it on front-end is not efficient. I decided to make all calculations with raw data on the server and get response. This should be done via AJAX request. According to Flux architecture I need to put them to store and them component should take it from there. However, creation of new store (like ReportStore) does not make sense. How should I deal with this? Can I directly request data from component and violate pattern? If yes, could you please provide sample code for with.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a `ReportStore`? `Reports` are data that you want to read on the client and display in component. If you want to use AJAX to initiate the data load I would use a helper component like this to request your reports from the frontend.

```
var ReportViewActions = {

   getReports: function(requestObject) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/reports',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: requestObject
        }).then(function(newReports) {
            AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                type: ReportActionTypes.RECEIVE_REPORTS,
                reports: newReports
            });
        });
   }
}
```

and listen to the event in the store. This way if you ever want to push reports or have other components subscribe to the `ReportStore` everything is already set up.

Comment: Also if you ever need server push you will be happy that you set up the store. I have tried to skip adding stores a few times and I always seem to need to add them later, or wish that I did.